# Services Module Authentication with Username and Password in URL

Tags: services, tokens, users

I have to match the following format when implementing Services to maintain some legacy APIs that were poorly written. I understand this is horrible practice and we're going to provide a new better OAUTH2 option going forward but that doesn't change my issue.

https://www.example.com/service/ServiceController.svc?username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&travelCode=TRAVEL_CODE

Short of writing my own authorization module that works with Services can anyone think of a method for getting this done using existing modules and Services.

I have tried Services Basic Authentication and Secure Services and either I am missing something or they don't do what I need.

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't want to customize something if I don't have to.

Comment: why not rely on session authentication?

Comment: Because the calls are going to be made by an automated system on the other end, they need to make a single call like the structure above to get their API results. They will not have a session when making the call.

Comment: so you should implement one of the module hooks and authenticate the user in code besides check matching of travelcode

Comment: <sarcasm>Well thanks for that wonderful insight it was just the help I was looking for.</sarcasm> The Services module user authentication is done by implementing other modules for authentication and implementing an object variable with a call back to the user authentication function. In order to get the user name and password from the plain text url strings I am going to have to implement Retrieve arguments and right custom verification code. However, if someone else has already gone through this struggle I was hoping for advice or examples.

Comment: If some one faced he will surely advice you, BTW consider upvoting to be get high question rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the following argument entries to my retrieve operation for my custom service I was able to achieve the desired effect.

```
                'args' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'none',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'Function to perform',
                        'source' => array(
                            'path' => '0'
                        ),
                        'optional' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '0',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'version',
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'description' => 'Function to perform',
                        'source' => array(
                            'param' => 'version'
                        ),
                        'optional' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '0',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'username',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'Function to perform',
                        'source' => array(
                            'param' => 'username'
                        ),
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                        'default' => '0',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'password',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'Function to perform',
                        'source' => array(
                            'param' => 'password'
                        ),
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                        'default' => '0',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'Function to perform',
                        'source' => array(
                            'param' => 'id'
                        ),
                        'optional' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '0',
                    ),
```